# Using a list of views to populate a listview

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created a list of custom views `Tickets` which I have extracted the `View` objects from. The code:

```
<ContentPage>
    <ListView ItemsSource="Tickets"/>
</ContentPage>
```

gives the following result:

[image]

I see that the `ToString()` is being inserted here, where I actually want the view tamplate itself to be inserted.
Is is possible to achieve this with the current version of xamarin?

Comment: No, and I'm not sure why you would want to.  Generally you want the UI abstracted from the data/model, this does the exact opposite.

Comment: I see what you mean. I am doing it because I was curious if it would work or not, and I could not find any sources on a similar thing. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Did you try in code behind? `var viewcell = new viewcell; viewcell.children.add(/*your stacklayout*/ ); listview.children.add(viewcell);`

Comment: That was my first thought as well. However, there doesn't seem to be a `Children` property of `ListView` can access directly like that. They seem to be bound by `ItemsSource` only.